# how to determine which imputed data to use in R

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, mice

I have a dataset of almost 100 variables. These variables are Likert scale questions from 1 to 5 or 1 to 3.

I converted the variables that I wanted to impute to categorical variables. Then I used this code:

```
imputed_data <- mice(selected_columns, m = 5, maxit = 10, method = "pmm", seed = 500)
```

Now I have five versions of imputed data. Which one to use?

The questionnaire items will be summed together to get the score of specific measurements, and these measurements will be compared between two groups. I have <5% of missing data in each variable and around 420 rows of data.

Using this line gives me one dataset, but I don't know how this was calculated or how to write in my paper how was this the imputed dataset was decided.

```
pooled_data <- complete(imputed_data)
```

Answer (score 4):

You use **all** multiply imputed datasets. The final analysis is based on conducting each analysis in each multiply imputed dataset, and then pooling them, such as with Rubin's Rules. This is the `pool` function, and there are copious examples on the internet, such as [here](https://amices.org/mice/reference/pool.html). Or just read the `mice` vignette and help files in R.

`complete` should only be used for non-standard analyses when you need to program the pooling rules by-hand, otherwise the imputed values are just synthetic and have no intrinsic value for reporting or analyses.

Comment: Not "you CAN use all multiply imputed data sets" but rather you have to. That is sort of the whole point of multiple imputation. And the complete() method isn't wrong, it's just only needed for nonstandard analysis.   You seem to be doing something non-standard, and, sorry, but that is probably not something for a beginner to do.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others that you should not be performing an advanced analysis like multiple imputation if you don't understand it. To perform your analysis in each imputed dataset, you need to use `with(.)`, and to pool the results you need to use `summary(pool(.))`.

You mentioned that you want to compare two groups, but not do regression. Comparing two groups is regression. This is the code you might run:

```r
with(imputed_data, lm(I(item1 + item2 + item3 + item4 + item5) ~ group)) |>
  pool() |> summary()
```

This runs a regression of the sum of your five items on your grouping variable (obviously replace the variable names with the correct names in your dataset). The coefficient on the grouping variable is the estimate of the difference between the group means.